# Is it possible to replace an AlertDialog's view after the dialog is shown?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

E.g.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setView(someView);
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
... then later ...
dialog.setView(someOtherView);
```

Code executes with no error, but view is not replaced in the dialog.  Am I doing it wrong or is this not possible?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No this is not possible. Try to dismiss the alert box and set your view and show it again.

Comment: I assume then it is also not possible to modify the dialog buttons (e.g. add another button) after the dialog is shown?

Answer (score 3):

### I'm not sure why but when using the alert dialog builder setView() does not work but setContentView() does

I think the alert dialog builder does not build the alert dialog in the conventional way in order to be compatible with all version of android so you will need to update the content view.

[Dialog.setContentView(View view)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setContentView(android.view.View))

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setView(view);
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

then later

```
alertDialog.setContentView(newView);
```

---

### It maybe easier to just rebuild a new alert dialog

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setView(view);
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

then later

```
alertDialog.dismiss();
AlertDialog.Builder updatedBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
updatedBuilder.setView(updatedView);
AlertDialog updatedAlertDialog = builder.create();
updatedAlertDialog.show();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately, `setContentView()` replaces all contents of the dialog, not only the part added with `setView()`.